# Navigation in . net Maui: Passing parameters

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to pass some properties from my viewmodel to another page to make data binding after that in the UI side  So this is the logic of my QuizDisplayViewModel which i want from it to pass the properties of the score, correctAnswer, totalAnswer to my LoadingQuiz page :

```
`[QueryProperty(nameof(QuizId),nameof(QuizId))]
public partial class QuizDisplayViewModel : BaseViewModel
{          
    public ObservableCollection<QuestionVM> QuestionsVM { get; } = new();
    QuizDisplayService quizDisplayService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private int _currentQuestionIndex;
    private int _totalQuestionsNumber;

    public int QuizId { get; set; }

    private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get => isLoading;
        set => SetProperty(ref isLoading, value);
    }
   
    public int CurrentQuestionIndex
    {
        get => _currentQuestionIndex;
        set => SetProperty(ref _currentQuestionIndex, value);
    }
    public int TotalQuestionsNumber
    {
        get => _totalQuestionsNumber;
        set => SetProperty(ref _totalQuestionsNumber, value);
    }
    private bool _isOptionSelected;
    public bool IsOptionSelected
    {
        get => _isOptionSelected;
        set
        {
            _isOptionSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOptionSelected));
        }
    }

    private int _totalCorrectAnswers;
    public int TotalCorrectAnswers
    {
        get => _totalCorrectAnswers;
        set => SetProperty(ref _totalCorrectAnswers, value);
    }

    private double _score;
    public double Score
    {
        get => _score;
        set => SetProperty(ref _score, value);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void Proceed()
    {
        // Get the current question
        QuestionVM currentQuestion = QuestionsVM[CurrentQuestionIndex];

        // Check if the user has selected a correct answer
        if (currentQuestion.Options.Any(o => o.IsSelected && o.IsCorrect))
        {
            TotalCorrectAnswers++;
        }

        // Hide the current question
        currentQuestion.IsVisible = false;

        // If there is another question, show it
        if (CurrentQuestionIndex < QuestionsVM.Count - 1)
        {
            CurrentQuestionIndex++;
            QuestionsVM[CurrentQuestionIndex].IsVisible = true;
        }
        else // No more questions, go to QuizSummary
        {
            Score = (TotalCorrectAnswers / (double)QuestionsVM.Count) * 100;
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz));
        }
    }
```

`

**How can i pass these properties with the navigation ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `IDictionary<string, object>` as a second parameter to `Shell.GoToAsync()` function.

```
IDictionary<string, object> navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { nameof(Score), Score },
    { "correctAnswer", new { complex = "object" } },
    { "totalAnswer", new object[]
        {
            new { possibly = "collection" },
            new { ofAny = "type of items" }
        }
    }
};
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz), navigationParameters);
```

I hope this helps!